# NGINX: How to use set variable from nginx.conf to Nginx C language policy?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Example of nginx.conf

```
server {
    set $abc_variable "abcabc";
    ........
}
```

How can I access abc_variable with the help of module api defined here https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/extending/api/

I'm using following code

```
ngx_str_t var = ngx_string("abc_variable");
ngx_uint_t key = ngx_hash_strlow(var.data, var.data, var.len);
ngx_http_variable_value_t *val = NULL;
val = ngx_http_get_variable(r, &var, key);
```

But I'm getting follow error

```
019/12/04 01:24:02 [notice] 12442#0: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 12444
2019/12/04 01:24:02 [alert] 12442#0: worker process 12444 exited on signal 11 (core dumped)
2019/12/04 01:24:02 [notice] 12442#0: start worker process 12561
2019/12/04 01:24:02 [notice] 12442#0: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
2019/12/04 01:24:02 [debug] 12561#0: setting SA_RESTART for signal 1
```

Comment: did you check if you have `HttpRewriteModule` module installed?  "set" directive is defined by this module.

Comment: @deepcell I'm able to use `set` in config, but what I want is to import that defined key-value from .conf to module api

Comment: Hey I hit the exact issue. It seems like `ngx_http_get_variable` can sometimes just return bogus result --- that when a variable doesn't actually exist, yet it returns none-NULL result with even `not_found` or `valid` flag set as if it's found, yet with a very wrong large number for the `len` field. That's what happened to me. Have you ever found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngx-http-get-variable](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/extending/api/variables/#ngx-http-get-variable).

Comment: Use gdb to find the reason.  Run `gdb path/to/the/nginx/binary path/to/the/core`  then input `bt full` to find which line to cause this core dump. Please note that your nginx source must be compiled with debug option, e.g. `CFLAGS="-g -O0" auto/configure`